# Java - Do not delete files that match any of the array values

Tags: java

I have a list of files(approximately 500 or more files) where the filename contains a date.

file_20180810

file_19950101

file_20180809

etc.

What I want to do is delete files which exceed the storage period.
I've come up with the following logic so far

> ~Get dates of valid storage period (ie. if storage period is 5 days and date today is 20180810, store date values 20180810, 20180809, 20180808, 20180807, 20180806, 20180805 in an array.
>
> ~Check every file in a directory if it contains any of the following dates. If it contains date, don't delete, else delete.

My problem here is, if the file name does contain one single date and I use a loop to delete a file, it might delete other files with valid dates as well. To show what I want to do in code form, it goes somehow like this:

```
 if (!fileName.contains(stringDate1) && 
 !fileName.contains(stringDate2) && 
 !fileName.contains(stringDate3)) //...until storage period
 {//delete file}
```

Is there a better way to express this? Any suggestions for a workaround?
Please and thank you.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, your approach seems pretty overkill. I would go with something like this (pseudocode): `foreach file: if file.name < "file_" + today.minusDays(5).format("yyyyMMdd"): delete file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse dates from your filename. Here's an example:

```
import java.time.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        long storagePeriod = 5L;
        String fileName = "file_20180804";
        int year = 0;
        int month = 0;
        int day = 0;

        String pattern = "file_(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})";
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = r.matcher(fileName);

        if (m.find()) {
            year = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
            month = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
            day = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));
        }

        LocalDate fileDate = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);

        if (fileDate.isBefore(today.minusDays(storagePeriod))) {
            System.out.println("Delete this file");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Regex to extract the actual date of each file and check for the inclusion in a validity period.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("file_(?<date>\d{6})");
foreach(File f : filelist){
    Matcher m = p.matcher(f.filename());
    if(m.find()){
        Date fileDate = new Date(m.group("date"));
        if(fileDate.before(periodStartDate)){
            file.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

The code is not precise and should not compile, check about `Date` object creation and comparison, but the main idea is pretty much here.

Answer (score 0):

You can only delete Files that are not in the Array like (tested, working):

```
    String path = ""; // <- Folder we want to clean.

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd"); // <- DateFormat to convert the Calendar dates into our format.
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // <- Using Calendar to get the days backwards.
    ArrayList<String> dr = new ArrayList<String>(); // <- Save the dates we want to remove.    dr = don't remove

    dr.add(df.format(cal.getTime())); // <- add the actual date to List
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // <- Loop 5 Times to get the 5 Last Days
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1); // <- remove 1 day from actual Calendar date
        dr.add(df.format(cal.getTime())); // <- add the day before to List
    }

    for(File file : new File(path).listFiles()) { // <- loop through all the files in the folder
        String filename = file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().lastIndexOf(".")); // <- name of the file without extension

        boolean remove = true; // <- Set removing to "yes"
        for(String s : dr) { // <- loop through all the allowed dates
            if(filename.contains(s)) { // <- when the file contains the allowed date
                remove = false; // <- Set removing to "no"
                break; // <- Break the loop for better performance
            }
        }

        if(remove) { // <- If remove is "yes"
            file.delete(); // <- Delete the file because it's too old for us!
        }
    }
```

but this is not the best way! A much better method would be to calculate how old the files are. Because of the _ you can pretty easily get the dates from the filenames. Like (not tested):

```
    String path = ""; // <- Folder we want to clean.
    Date today = new Date();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd"); // <- Dateformat you used in the files
    long maxage = 5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // <- Calculate how many milliseconds ago we want to delete

    for(File file : new File(path).listFiles()) { // <- loop through all the files in the folder
        String fds = file.getName().split("_")[1]; // <- Date from the filename as string
        try {
            Date date = df.parse(fds); // Convert the string to a date

            if(date.getTime() - today.getTime() <= maxage) { // <- when the file is older as 5 days 
                file.delete(); // <- Delete the file
            }

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example code which demonstrates how a list of input files (file name strings, e.g., "file_20180810") can be verified against a supplied set of date strings (e.g., "20180810") and perform an operation (like delete the file) on them.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class FilesTesting {
    private static final int DATE_STRING_LENGTH = 8; //  length of 20180809
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        List<String> filter = Arrays.asList("20180810", "20180808", "20180809", "20180807", "20180806", "20180805");
        List<File> files = Arrays.asList(new File("file_20180810"), new File("file_19950101"), new File("file_20180809"));
        for (File file : files) {
            String fileDateStr = getDateStringFromFileName(file.getName());
            if (filter.contains(fileDateStr)) {
                // Do something with it
                // Delete file - if it exists
                System.out.println(file.toString());
            }
        }
    }
    private static String getDateStringFromFileName(String fileName) {
        int fileLen = fileName.length();
        int dateStrPos = fileLen - DATE_STRING_LENGTH;
        return fileName.substring(dateStrPos);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you’re using ES6 you can use array includes and return a true or false to validate.

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].includes('b')
```

Comment: Java, not Javascript.

Comment: Argh! My apologies. Although, think of the the concept. Create an array of strings. Loop through values FOUND or NOT FOUND in an array of strings. Compare it to your target string. Return true or false.